# Publish a post at a later time

Tags: php, mysql

column `later` is `datetime` and some fields have the value `2017-05-01 04:07:00`.
I want to change some fields in the rows where current date and time is greater then `later` value.

The purpose is to publish a post which has being setting to publish later.

```
$current = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$sql = "update posts set status = :astatus, user = :auser, pass = :apass where later < :alater";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ":astatus" => 'public',
    ":auser" => '',
    ":apass" => '',
    ":alater" => $current
));
```

Nothing is changed.

Comment: I don't see a problem with how you are running the SQL.  Which makes me think the problem is with your data or schema.  I recommend you create a test case at http://sqlfiddle.com/ to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing the time in, use the database time:

```
$sql = "update posts set status = :astatus, user = :auser, pass = :apass where later < now()";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ":astatus" => 'public',
    ":auser" => '',
    ":apass" => ''
));
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose i have to show post after one hrs from the posting time I simply use cron job

suppose i have post 
sr  from location   to location created date
1   Pune            Nagpur      2017-07-29 05:00:00

I have to show this post at 2017-07-29 06:00:

simply i run cron job in the interval of 5 minute 
check whether created time is current time if yes the show and maintain sum flag .